# Fragment ListView onItemClick Highlights Incorrect Item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, android-adapterview

I have a `ListView` that is contained within a `Fragment`. In the `onCreateView` section I have set a `onItemClickListener` for the list. My intention was to highlight the item selected, however upon click the space between `ListViewItems` are colored instead of the item itself.
I've also considered using a `Selector` but have been unsuccessful, IE:        `view.setBackgroundDrawable(view.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_selector));`

Is there a way to correct this? Or does it necessitate bringing in a new `Row` with `LayoutInflater`? Thanks in advance.

Fragment

```
 public static class FragmentRoutine extends Fragment {
    DatabaseHandler db;
    private ListView routineListView;
    private List<Routine> routines = new ArrayList<Routine>();
    ArrayAdapter<Routine> routineAdapter;
    Routine longClickedItemRoutines;
    private SelectedAdapter selectedAdapter;
    ImageButton btnMoveUp,btnMoveDown;
    public FragmentRoutine() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routines,
                container, false);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        routineListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.routineList);
        registerForContextMenu(routineListView);
        db.closeDB();
        if (db.getRoutineCount() != 0)
            routines.clear();
        routines.addAll(db.getAllRoutines());
        populateList();
        selectedAdapter = new SelectedAdapter(this.getActivity(),0,routines);
        selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        routineListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                longClickedItemRoutines = routines.get(position);
                return false;
            }
        });
        routineListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                for (int h = 0; h < adapterView.getChildCount(); h++)
                    adapterView.getChildAt(h).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                // change the background color of the selected element
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
        });// move up event handler

        ImageButton btnMoveUp =(ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnMoveUp);
        btnMoveUp.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                moveUp();
            }
        });

        // move down event handler
        ImageButton btnMoveDown =(ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnMoveDown);
        btnMoveDown.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                moveDown();
            }
        });

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not update view in `setOnItemClickListener`, instead, record the position in this function:

**update**

```
mActiveListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    sSelectedIndex = position;
    // notify ListView's ArrayAdapter that the data attached has been changed, 
    // and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.
    yourArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

And then update your fragment listview in `getView` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_menu, null);
    }

    if (position == sSelectedIndex) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(...);
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(...);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. How would you set the list to `onListItemClick`? I don't see a way to implement it. IE: `routineListView.set...`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method still highlights the regions between items.

Comment: *Correction* li you were right! Haha, this one was MY fault. I had added another `ArrayAdapter` and something went a miss. I'll mark this in a few moments. If you want to note for others `convertView` is the key here. Also the addition of `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` above the `return` statement grants list functionality. Thanks again!

Comment: yeah, @Austin you're right, we should call `notifyDataSetChanged` to tell  ListView's ArrayAdapter that the data attached has been changed, and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself. :)

Comment: Update: For best user experience calling `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onItemClick` and not in `getView` method provides the fastest response . IE no lag.

Comment: Posted my last before I saw your reply, haha. Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

The error lies within your setOnItemClickListener on routineListView.

More specifically the `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);` part.
The view you're getting passed here is your ListView, not the clicked list element. So you're setting the background color of the entire listview instead of the single element. But the single elements are on top of the listview, so the only places you can see the color is in between the list elements.

To correct this, you should do the following:

```
routines.get(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

That will correctly get the clicked list element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think what you mentioned is in the right direction, however, it will not allow the passing of `.setBackgroundColor` as it recognizes `.get(position)` as an `int` from the `onItemClick`'s parameters. Thoughts?